# Android: How to Resume Application/Activity from BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

If my procedure is following:

1. Launch Activity A -> Activity B
2. Press 'Home' button.
3. Click on the application again.

**Result:** 'Activity B' shows up (it **resumes**).

1. Launch Activity A -> Activity B
2. Press 'Back' button.
3. Click on the application again.

**Result:** 'Activity A' shows up (it **restarts**).

I want to do exactly same from the BroadcastReceiver.

1. Launch Activity A -> Activity B
2. Press 'Home' button.
3. BroadcastReceiver receives a broadcast and want to "resume" application.

**My expected result:** 'Activity B' shows up.

I want to do exactly same from the BroadcastReceiver.

1. Launch Activity A -> Activity B
2. Press 'Back' button.
3. BroadcastReceiver receives a broadcast and want to "restart" application.

**Current result:** 'Activity A' shows up.

Following code doesn't do what I expect:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, ActivityA.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
```

I also tried "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY" but no luck.

Comment: You mean the activity A didn't show up after you start activity A with a new task flag?

Comment: Anyway you can try use `singleTask` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to achieve it.

Comment: No, I want 'Activity B' to show up if 'Home' button was pressed.

Comment: I tried singleTask and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK but it's not resuming to Acitivity B when 'Home' button is pressed.

Comment: Declare your activity B launch mode is `single task`, and then start it with your code above besides changing the `ActivityA.class` to `ActivityB.class`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My gosh, I made it working!!

Thank you for other answers you guys provided, but they weren't what I was looking for.

This will do the job:

```
Intent i = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.your.package.name");
i.setFlags(0);
i.setPackage(null);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I am glad to know that you solve your problem. accept your own ansser

Comment: This comment in the android source file ActivityStack.java explains why:                             // In this case we are launching the root activity
                            // of the task, but with a different intent.  We
                            // should start a new instance on top.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I have been looking for this the whole day @.@ I don't know why the solution using Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK doesn't work. It is specified in the official docs! http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Care to explain why your answer works?

Answer (score 4):

check out this

set flags to your intent `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`  and

`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` as following

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```