# onNewIntent() is not getting called when Intent flag is set to FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Tags: android, android-intent

As per the below documentation from `developer.android.com onNewIntent(-)` callback method will be called when we set the flag `Intnet.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.
 http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

but for me when i sent this flag to my activity , `onNewIntent()` is not been called when i launched the activity via shortcut. But it is launching with the state where it was been previously saved.

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MyMenu.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);



    <activity
        android:name="com.myPackage.MyMenu"           
        android:theme="@style/noAnimTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />                
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Could you please post your `startActivity` and `onNewIntent` code?

Comment: @zozelfelfo I just updated, please check once..

Comment: why do you need a `context` if you are already in the activity?

Comment: show your manifest for MyMenu activity

Comment: @marcin_j I just updated, Please check once..

Comment: @zozelfelfo : I am launching this Activity inside onReceive() of a BroadcastReceiver

Comment: @sureshn have you tried adding android:launchMode="singleTop" ? Also look into this SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881976/android-how-to-resume-application-activity-from-broadcastreceiver

Comment: @all finally i am able to resolve by keeping launchMode as "singleTask" in manifest.xml . by this way onNewIntent() is being called. But still have confusion why onNewIntent() is called when set the flag to Intnet.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK via programatically.